# Can I add the free 20MB SQL DB to an exiting Azure website?

Tags: database, azure

I have an existing azure website. When I created it, I did not select to add the 20MB free database option.  Is there a way to add this?
Thanks

Comment: What payment tier are you on? I was wondering if you get a 20MB DB with the free tier as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a second website with the free 20MB database, copy the connection string to the first website. That should be all. You could even delete the second site, just be sure t